# php cant change cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

Php8 cant change cookie value but can set cookie with value

### testcooike.php

```
<?php
setcookie("cookieTest","dog",time()+800000, '/');
echo "cookie before change ";
echo $_COOKIE["cookieTest"];
echo " after change ";
$_COOKIE["cookieTest"]="cat";
echo $_COOKIE["cookieTest"];
```

**result**
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jx8Yt.png)

### testcookie2.php

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["cookieTest"];
```

**result** [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kGQQ.png)

**notes**

- testcookie2.php launched after testcooike.php
- also testcooike.php and testcookie2.php launched in chrome browser

Comment: Cookies are sent as part of a HTTP response (in the response's headers) to the browser (that's what `setcookie` does and that's why you need to do it before any actual output is rendered). You can change things around in $_COOKIE all you want but you should look into it as a read-only array. It's values are populated from the cookies sent by the browser as part of the request so, any changes to it will not persist (you're essentially changing a value that will be recreated at each request). In short: use `setcookie` to set and/or update cookie values.

Comment: Now it's working thanks for answer